# MongoDB ,Update specific object from array in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

the collection UserTransactions is like this:-

```
date = new Date().getTime()
UserTransactions = [
{ 
  _id : ObjectId('6273dbe015989a3dcd02bf81')
  transactions : [{
        _id : ObjectId('62b46c7071140f64cbf610c0')
        quantity : 2
        available_from :1665991408904
        expiry :1761351408904
      },{
       _id : ObjectId('62b46d2771140f64cbf610c3')
        quantity : 2
        available_from :1655991408904
        expiry :16621351408904
      },{
        _id : ObjectId('62454d7037edf7501f44d0e4')
        quantity : 2
        available_from :1755991408904
        expiry :1971351408904
      }]
},
{ 
  _id : ObjectId('6273dbe015989a3dcd02bf79')
  transactions : [{
        _id : ObjectId('62b46c7071140f64cbf610c0')
        quantity : 2
        available_from :1665991408904
        expiry :1761351408904
      },{
       _id : ObjectId('62b46d2771140f64cbf610c3')
        quantity : 2
        available_from :1655991408904
        expiry :16621351408904
      },{
        _id : ObjectId('62454d7037edf7501f44d0e4')
        quantity : 2
        available_from :1755991408904
        expiry :1971351408904
      }]
}
]
```

I want to update the object from transactions array whose **expiry is lowest** and date is between "available_from" and "expiry".
The query I have tried is

```
await UserTransactions.updateOne(
{ _id: given_id, transactions: { $elemMatch:{ available_from:{ $lt: new Date().getTime() }, expiry: { $gt:new Date().getTime() }}}},
{  $inc: { "transactions.$.quantity": -1 }}
)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection("transactions").updateOne({ _id: lowestExpiry._id }, { $set: { available: true }})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.